# GridLayout renders differently than in preview

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

In my calculator app, I use a GridLayout to layout all the buttons. In the Android Studio preview it looks like this:

[image]

Yet when I run my app on a Nexus 5x emulator it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code of my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.abc.deskcalculator.MainActivity"

    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:columnCount="7"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mode"
        android:layout_columnSpan="7"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RAD"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/window"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="7"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text=""
        android:minLines="2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:background="@drawable/window_border"/>

    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/bkspc"
        android:text="@string/bkspc"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/clr"
        android:text="@string/clr"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="@string/switchDegRadGrad"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/lparen"
        android:text="@string/lparen"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/rparen"
        android:text="@string/rparen"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="floor"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="ceil"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="√"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="log"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="ln"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/dig7"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/dig8"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/dig9"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/opDiv"
        android:text="@string/opDiv"
        />
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="x²"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="EE"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="exp"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/dig4"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/dig5"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/dig6"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/opMul"
        android:text="@string/opMul"
        />
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="π"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="a^b"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:text="cbrt"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/dig1"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:id="@+id/dig2"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:id="@+id/dig3"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:id="@+id/opSub"
        android:text="@string/opSub"
        />
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="sin"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="cos"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="tan"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="@string/decpt"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:id="@+id/dig0"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"
        android:id="@+id/neg"
        android:text="@string/neg"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="@string/opAdd"
        android:id="@+id/opAdd"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="asin"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="acos"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="atan"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:id="@+id/varAns"
        android:text="@string/varAns"/>
    <Button
        style="@style/calcBtnApperance"

        android:text="@string/equals"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/equals"/>
</GridLayout>
```

STYLES.XML

```
<style name="calcBtnApperance">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fd3d3d3d</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">49dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

(I know this code is repetitive, but I posted the full thing just in case.)

How can I make there not be such a big gap before the last column?

Also, how can I make each cell of the table get narrower as new columns are added without having to adjust the `android:minWidth` attribute each time I add a new column? Had I not set that attribute, then the buttons would keep going past the end of the screen.

I think these two are symptoms of the same problem.

My Min SDK is 17

EDIT: The digits were filled in programatically, which is why you don't see them in the Android Studio preview.

Answer (score 1):

Change you `GridLayout` attributes.

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and put your `GridLayout` inside `LinearView` and add `gravity` and `orientation` attribute

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

However, I suppose this design if tested on smaller devices some of the buttons will go out of the screen

Comment: Those two `orientation` and `gravity` attributes go on the `LinearView` or on the `GridLayout`?

Comment: Won't let me get rid of `layout_width` and layout_height`--they are required

Comment: LinearView width and height should match_parent